# Best way to display various context menus depending on the sentence clicked in an android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, contextmenu

I'm displaying a large amount of text((In a text view), and for each sentence, I would like to be able to long press and display options based on the current sentence (for example: a context menu with all the words that I have extended definitions for).

For example I have the following text:
The dog ate and ran. The cat sat down.
When longpressing the area for the first sentence, a context menu would show up allowing me to select dog and run (since I have definitions for those in my engine). The second sentence would pull up cat. (The words the engine selects for the engine are theoretical for now, the real question is on the context menu)

How would I do that? Would I have to create TextViews for every single sentence and then add the long press context menu to every single one of them? Or is there any other way?

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Are you having list of data? I mean Arrays of data

Answer (score 1):

I think you ought to have a look at this

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html

followed by this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

What you are trying looks interesting, though could end up being a pretty tedious process unless the above links help.

Comment: Ended up doing a linearlayout and created a textview for each sentence. It makes a new line for each sentence but it's something I can deal with it for now